# Selecting Distinct IDs From a Table

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like such:

```
firstName    ID
 Mike        1
 James       2
 Mike        3
 Sally       4
 Emma        5
 Sally       6
```

and am trying to get an output that returns each person who has more than 1 different ID, and what those IDs are. In my example it would be like such:

```
firstName    ID
 Mike        1
 Mike        3
 Sally       4
 Sally       6
```

I am working on it and have something like what is below but it is erroring. There is something in the logic I am clearly missing but I am struggling to see what it is. Can someone point me in the direction of what is wrong here?

```
SELECT firstName, ID
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You select names with more than one id using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.firstName = t.firstName and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```